# G1 OU reduce when young gc happened

Tags: jvm, g1gc

```
env:jdk8
VM flag:-Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -XX:+UseG1GC (other flags as default)
```

From the gc log, there is no mixed gc.Why the young gc decreasing the OU?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: assuming there no mixed collection happend as you said that then it might be a trivially-proven-unreachable old region or humongous region getting marked as free. you should look at GC logs instead of jstat output if you want more details. jstat is woefully inadequate to represent the different phases of modern GCs.

Comment: supply the gc log as post.No concurrent marking happened here.

Comment: You could try logging with `G1TraceEagerReclaimHumongousObjects`, that should show when humongous regions are reclaimed.

Comment: I will try it later.Thx.